# Projector matrix question

Tags: linear-algebra

Let AB = Q; where Q is mxn; B is nxn; and Q*Q = I: Show that Q*Q  is the orthogonal projection of R^m onto the range of A.

Can someone help me on this, problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is not generally true; it only holds if $B$ is full rank.  For instance, take $B=0$; then $Q=0$.